# How can I keep the IconButton inside a TextField from focusing the text field when the button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is my code for the text field inside my scaffold:

```
child: TextField(
  obscureText: _obscureText,
  controller: myController2,
  focusNode: myFocusNode2,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  onSubmitted: (value){
    myFocusNode2.unfocus();
    _loginMethod();
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Password",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off: Icons.visibility),
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          _obscureText = !_obscureText;
        });
        Timer.run(() => myFocusNode2.unfocus());
      },
    )
  ),
),
```

What I have right now works, but it is not clean at all. Most of the time the text field becomes focused for a second then the .unfocus() unfocuses it after a delay, so I get this jump effect with the keyboard popping up and then going back down. Only a few times the text field will never get focused at all and I don't understand why.

Is there a way to make sure the IconButton never focuses the text field when it is pressed?

Comment: Perhaps `FocusNode()` may help. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html

Comment: The suffix icon lies within the text field and hence during the hit-testing, the text field gets the focus first. You should rather Wrap the text field and icon button in a row widget. But, the IconButton will be outside the border this way. If you want it inside the border, you can remove decoration of the text field and perhaps wrap the entire row in a decorated container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just can think of 3 solutions, not prefect but just get the job done

1- use focusNode with timer

after you link foucsNode to the textfiled the button function could be something like this

```
          onPressed: () {
            Timer.periodic(Duration(microseconds: 1), (_) {
              focusNode.unfocus();
            });
            //Write your code here
          },
```

2- use stack

```
Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
              onPressed: () {
                //do any thing
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

3- as  Afridi Kayal said you can use a row

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                enabled: enabled,
                autofocus: false,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Password",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.visibility),
              onPressed: () {
                print('object');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

if you end up going with number 2 or 3 and you want to make the button color change when you focus on the textfiled, you can do it by using focusNode as well.

Comment: Thank you for this! The first option did not work for me, but the second worked perfectly. To fit my use case, I created a listener on the text field for focus changes, and if the text field had focus it would change the color of the icon to the border color. However, the listener doesn't work when the field is tapped so I also had an onTap: () {} function in the text field to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExcludeFocus/ExcludeFocusTraversal](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ExcludeFocus-class.html) widgets